# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Adding analytics labels to messages

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I have a very specific question for web push notification via the FCM: how do I add analytics labels to my notifications?

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#adding-analytics-labels-to-messages):

> Labeling messages is very useful for custom analysis, allowing you to
> filter delivery statistics by labels or sets of labels. You can add a
> label to any message sent via the HTTP v1 API by setting the
> fcmOptions.analyticsLabel field in the message object

I am sending my push notification via a Node.js Firebase Cloud Function using the [`messaging.send(Message)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging-1#send) method. When I read the documentation of the [`Message`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.TopicMessage) object I understand that the only place to set this label in my case is here:

```
{
  ...
  fcmOptions: {analyticsLabel: [string}
  ...
}
```

Is this correct? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591181/firebase-cloud-messaging-set-analytics-label-with-nodejs) on SO also seems to indicate so

I have done this and I still dont see the label appearing in my Firebase Console, by this I mean when I go to [https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/{myprojectname}/notification/reporting](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/%7Bmyprojectname%7D/notification/reporting) and I try to filter by data I get no data:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

i think that your code is OK. In my case, reports in FCM have error from 05/14/2021. I have just sent ticket to FB 's support. If I get any news, i will reply.

Update 02/06/2021:
From Firebase's support team : "*We’ve received similar reports regarding this issue, and I would like to include your project details to that report*" ==> Wait FB engineer team resolve this problem. Continue update when i have new message.

Comment: Last time I got successful reports was on April. I did 2 pushes on 25th and 28th of May and none of them are reporting the sends. The labels used also do not appear on FCM filters. There was no code changes during this period on my side.
Keep us updated pls

Comment: @vmintam, where do you see the errors in the FCM reports?

Comment: @l1b3rty: i use analytics_label base on HTTPV1, but i don't see anything in FCM report on Firebase Console. Before 14th of May, report was good.

Comment: can you please share the ticket? @vmintam

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was fixed a few days ago. At least our analytics dashboard in firebase console suddenly became normal and started to display sending events as well.
No release notes or even any answer from the firebase technical support team though. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @vmintam post, I leave here another feedback from Firebase's support team from some days ago.

*"Hello,
Here is an update from our team.
They have mitigated this issue on our end and are able to see the analytics_label. Unfortunately, they also won't be able to backfill the missing data during the outage, since the analytics_label was missing from that time. If still you aren't able to see the analytics_label, please reach back out with a screenshot displaying it."*

We already could confirm that "Sends" metric and analytics label is being registered again, so at least for us the problem is solved.